# Not able to show graph on click of a button

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Graph is not displayed on click. I have

I have two child components

1. Data component for showing the list of employees
2. Rating component for showing employee's respective rating

I have put 'graph code' inside 'ngOnInit' function in Rating component, and click button is in Data component, with help of event emitting i am trying to pass a boolean value from Data to Rating .
As you can see below in rating.component.html, if the flag value becomes true, then show graph. But even after flag becomes true, graph is not visible.

Data component

```
import { DataService } from './../../services/data.service';
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-data',
  templateUrl: './data.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data.component.css'],
})
export class DataComponent implements OnInit {
  users: { name: string; city: string }[] = [];
  visible = false;
  @Output() show  = new EventEmitter();
  constructor(private dataSerivce: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
   this.users = this.dataSerivce.getEmployees();
  }
  toggle() {
    this.visible = !this.visible;
    if (this.visible) {
      console.log('enter');
      this.show.emit(this.visible);
    } else {
      this.show.emit(null);
    }
  }

}
```

Rating component

```
import { Rating } from './../../../../models/rating.model';
import { DataService } from 'src/app/services/data.service';
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges} from '@angular/core';
import {Chart} from '../../../../node_modules/chart.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-rating',
  templateUrl: './rating.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./rating.component.css']
})
export class RatingComponent implements OnInit ,OnChanges{

   rating: Rating[] = [];
   @Input() flag = false;


  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('init');
    var myChart= new Chart('myChart', {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
          labels: ['Technical', 'Communication', 'Experience', 'Leadership'],
          datasets: [{
              label: 'skill scores',
              data: [10,15, 16, 22],
              backgroundColor: [
                  'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)'

              ],
              borderColor: [
                  'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                  'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)'

              ],
              borderWidth: 1
          }]
      },
      options: {
          scales: {
              yAxes: [{
                  ticks: {
                      beginAtZero: true
                  }
              }]
          }
      }
  });
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
       console.log('first time');

  }

  private getRatings($event){

       this.dataService.getRating().subscribe(res =>{
           this.rating.push(res);
       });
  }



}
```

Rating html code

```
<div style="height:40%;width:40%;" class="center" *ngIf ="flag" >
  <canvas
  class="chart chart-bar"
  chart-data="dataChart" id  = "myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you've posted the same code for RatingsComponent in the HTML part of your question. Can you edit that?

Answer (score 0):

While the `chart.js` options might be correct, the current code in `RatingComponent` is not referencing the `chart.js` options to any particular `DOM Element`. This could be one of the reasons why the chart is not getting rendered.

ChartJS expects a `reference` to a DOM Element which it shall use to render the chart.

For example:

HTML Template:

```
<div #barchart class="barChart"><d/iv>
```

RatingsComponent :

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';

  @Component({
    ...
  })

  export class RatingComponent implements OnInit {

    @ViewChild('barchart') private chartRef;
    chart: any;


    ngOnInit() {

        // provide reference of the html component to the the Chart Instance.
        this.chart = new Chart(this.chartRef.nativeElement, {
        // insert chart options here
        });
    
    }

}
```

**Alternatively**

After looking at your update, I think the part that is causing issue is that you are not passing the required data to the `canvas` component.

According to the documentation of [ChartJS](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/).

HTML Code:

```
<div>
  <div style="display: block">
    <canvas baseChart
            [datasets]="barChartData"
            [labels]="barChartLabels"
            [options]="barChartOptions"
            [legend]="barChartLegend"
            [chartType]="barChartType">
    </canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-bar-chart',
  templateUrl: './my-bar-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-bar-chart.component.css']
})

export class MyBarChartComponent implements OnInit {  constructor() { }        

    public barChartOptions = {
        scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
        responsive: true
    };  
    public barChartLabels = ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011',    '2012'];
    public barChartType = 'bar';
    public barChartLegend = true;  public barChartData = [
      {data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40], label: 'Series A'},
      {data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90], label: 'Series B'}
    ];  

  ngOnInit() {
  }}
```

Comment: chart is not rendered only when there is ngIf condition in html, after removing it works. But could not figure out the reason , why is it so??? Any thoughts on that

Comment: That is because the Component isnt able to find a reference to the DOM element in case of `ngIf`, try `ngShow` instead of `ngIf`

Comment: `ng-show` (and its sibling `ng-hide`) toggle the appearance of the element by adding the CSS `display: none` style. `ng-if` , on the other hand, actually removes the element from the DOM when the condition is false and only adds the element back once the condition turns true

Comment: exactly  but when the condition is true, then ng if should add the element to the DOM. right ??? or Am i missing something???

Comment: ngShow didn't work, chart is now visible all the time . Though related to ng show , i found another property [hidden] which worked. So thanks for your help  @DhruvShah

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz?